# Could an entry of a vector be called a dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

According to the definition, dimension means the number of entries of a vector. However, in a lot of research papers, people use "a dimension" to refer to "an entry". According to the definition of the word dimension (if you google the word dimension), dimension could be "an aspect or feature of a situation, problem, or thing" (Definitions from Oxford Language). That means dimension could be an entry. But in math, could it be used that way?

OK. I read some of your comments. Here is an example paper: "The Limitations of Deep Learning in Adversarial Settings" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07528.pdf)  page: 6 bottom left, above EQ. 4, " that is the derivative of one output neuron F_j according to one input dimension x_i".

To those who think the definition is not well formulated. Look at this book "Introduction to
Applied Linear Algebra" (http://vmls-book.stanford.edu/vmls.pdf) page 13: The size (also called dimension or length) of the vector is the number of
elements it contains

Comment: Could you please elaborate?  Which "people"?  How is "a dimension" used in context?

Comment: Be careful: The subspace $\{(x,0)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a one-dimensional vector space, but its vectors have two "entries". More general, there are vector-spaces without any "entries" (how would you define that anyhow, if you hadn't heard of isometries?). Consider a linear algebra textbook for a proper mathematical definition.

Comment: Your definition "dimension means the number of entries of a vector" is  not well formulated. First , this is a poor definition of the dimension of a vector space, not a general definition, how otherwise explain the dimension of all Polynoms  of grade <=5  ,2. please tell where you find and "entry" called dimension.

Comment: A single vector doesn't have a “dimension.”  Dimension is a property of a *vector space*.

Comment: *If* your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3$, *if* its basis is the standard / natural / canonical basis, then the entries of any vector coincide with its coordinates, and you can view the first entry as its width, the second entry as its length, the third entry as its depth.

Comment: @GrafZahl  I referred a book and quoted a sentence. See the update above. I was talking about the dimension of a vecor not a vector space.

Comment: @trula I referred a book and quoted a sentence. See the update above. I was talking about the dimension of a vecor not a vector space.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I referred a book and quoted a sentence. See the update above. I was talking about the dimension of a vecor not a vector space.

Comment: @Sergio I referred a book and quoted a sentence. See the update above. I was talking about the dimension of a vecor not a vector space.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Context is given in the paper I showed above.

Comment: While I agree the author of the second paper has called the number of entries in a vector the dimension or length this is nonstandard.  Dimensions typically apply to vector spaces not vectors themselves and are defined based on finding the number of basis vectors required to generate the space, not as an entry.

Comment: @CrazyMageQi Please, be careful. The book by Boyd & Vandenberghe is about "vectors, matrices, and least squares methods" (p. 9), it is *not* about vector spaces (see p. 461). In that book a vector is an "ordered finite list of numbers" (p. 13), but this is an (over)simplification. In linear algebra there are vector spaces whose elements are not lists of numbers, e.g. vector spaces of functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space)

Comment: @Sergio Exactly. This book is not about vector space and my question is not about vector space but about vector. Why do you bring up vector space in the first place? That is not relevant to answer my question.

Comment: in the book you have very special vectors, in form of  row of numbers, the book speaks of the "size" of a vector, it also calls it length, This is not the way mathematicians usually define vectors or dimension or length of vectors, so its not a very mathematical book of linear algebra, but maybe it is useful for engineers. So please do not take this definition as a mathematical definition, it is not! The part in the paper uses dimension not very well, but from the context it is clear, that it talks of a one dimensional object .

Comment: @trula You said " the book speaks of the "size" of a vector, it also calls it length". Why don't you admit it also calls it dimension? I literally excerpted it "The size (also called dimension or length) of the vector is the number of elements it contains" Scientists shouldn't use partial truth to justify themselves. I don't care if it is a very mathematical book. I just use it to prove "dimension" can mean "the number of entries of a vector" in certain situations and thus my illustration of the question I asked it legit. And I also care about the answer to my question not someone being picky.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the commenters are trying to say is that, in linear algebra as practiced by mathematicians, *dimension* is an aspect of a vector space rather than of an individual vector.   Mathematicians don't only consider finite lists of real numbers as vectors.  A function, or even an equivalence class of functions, can also be a vector, and there's no way to talk about the “entries” of such a vector.

You have found some examples in the literature of the word *dimension* being used as a synonym for *entry* (or *coordinate*, even).  But none of those authors are mathematicians.  So I think the answer to your actual question:

> But *in math*, could it [the word “dimension”] be used that way [as a synonym for “entry”]?

is “No; in math, the word dimension means something else entirely.”

Comment: According to your answer:
The book I mentioned is a math book. So the book is wrong in using dimension as the number of entries in a vector, right?
In that paper, did the author use the word "dimension" correctly?

Comment: The book you cited is not a mathematics book. The author used dimension not for a vector or a vector space, so it is up to him how he used it. No misunderstanding comes of this use, so why do you care?